# Learning Julia (Strings, For Loops, etc)?

Tags: coding-style, julia

Learning a programming language is always a challenge, because you are not familiar with the syntax or what functions are available. I decided to learn Julia because it has its focus in academia. On the Internez i read that it copies a lot of good things from Python. I have already worked with Python and enjoyed the `Pythonic` syntax.

I started with a calculation of bit values of 2 strings and this is my result.

```
function crypt(message, key)
    result = ""
    while length(result) < length(key)
        result *= string(Char(Int(message[length(result)+1]) $ Int(key[length(result)+1])))
    end
    return result
end
```

It looks really awkward and ugly in my eyes when i compare it to Python. But i could not find `any` Tutorials or Guides how to use this language. And the documentation on their website isn't much help neither.

> How do i learn this language? Where do i get information about it?

ps. Python:

```
def crypt(message, key):
    result = [chr(ord(m) ^ ord(k)) for m, k in zip(message, key)]
    return "".join(result)
```

Comment: Side note: In my experience it pays off in the long run to make strategic choices if it comes to decide which languages to learn. One or Two for systems programming (e.g. C/C++, Rust), one or two .NET languages (e.g. C#, F#) (which are already faster than python), one high level language (e.g. Haskell). Better to be knowledgable about a few than being a rookie in many languages.

Comment: best place to start Julialang is the first page of this manual: http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this looks close enough:

```
julia> function crypt(message, key)
          join([Char(Int(m) $ Int(k)) for (m, k) in zip(message, key)])
       end
crypt (generic function with 1 method)

julia> crypt("Hello", "world")
"?\n\x1e\0\v"
```

and not *that* much uglier than the Python. But beauty is in the eye of the beholder, as they say...

As for learning the language:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several basic tutorials listed on the Julia homepage at JuliaLang.org/learning.